# No matter what I do, this variable refuses to change value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

This **SHOULD** be simple. Instead it's confused the heck out of me for the last hour or so.

**Header file:**

*CellBackgroundView is a custom class derived from UIView.*

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    CellBackgroundView *customBackgroundView;

}

@property (strong) CellBackgroundView *customBackgroundView;
```

**Code that doesn't work as expected:**

All I want to do is assign something to customBackgroundView.

```
    customBackgroundView = [[CellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self addSubview:customBackgroundView];
```

-

Nothing happens. In the debugger, I can see that customBackgroundView is 0x0. The following doesn't work either, although "background" does get assigned a memory location. customBackgroundView is still 0x0.

```
    CellBackgroundView *background = [[CellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    customBackgroundView = background.
    [self addSubview:customBackgroundView];
```

What's happening? Why doesn't this work?
I have ARC turned on.

**EDITS:**

The basis of CellBackgroundView is:

```
- (BOOL) isOpaque {
    return NO;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect {
    //Custom drawing code
}
```

Also, the above code worked fine when I used the official 'backgroundView' property of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Anything relevant in CellBackgroundView implementation? Like a custom initWithFrame?

Comment: Can you post your `initWithFrame:` method for `CellBackgroundView`? It could be that passing it CGRectZero returns nil.

Comment: @madmw I've posted the basis of that class - see the edit at the bottom.

Comment: @jbat100 Thanks for the suggestion. I've only added two overridden methods to the class as above though. It's what I though at first too, but if that was the case, then "background" wouldn't get set to a value as shown above.

Comment: I would suggest that your initWithFrame method is returning nil, can you post the FULL code for that method.

Comment: @SimonLee I don't have that method, as it's a subclass, it just uses the default behavior from UIView. As explained above, this can't be why for a few reasons - mainly, it works when just setting it to a locally declared variable. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally.... the answer is indeed that Xcode is broken.

Or rather, the debugger is. Whatever I set that variable to, Xcode refuses to display in the debugger. However, the code actually works as it should.

Fix it please Apple.

Comment: Try xCode 4.2 with the latest iOS. I too have faced the problem you're facing with xCode 4.0!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) CellBackgroundView *customBackgroundView;
```

instead of `strong` and see if it helps...It's seems to be a memory assignment issue

Comment: No difference, good idea though. I've also tried 'assign', no luck that way either.

Comment: you must've synthesized the property too...you'll get a warning for that otherwise

Comment: Yea, it's synthesized too. I've even tried writing my own setters and getters thinking that this was messing it up somehow. Still, same behavior!

Comment: The problem is NOT in your `CellBackgroundView` class as `CellBackgroundView *background` works! The problem has to be in your `customBackgroundView` variable

Comment: Thanks, yea I'd come to that conclusion too. Still no progress though.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the type to a UIView. I took away the property and synthesize declaration. I 'cleaned' the project.

So my code is now just:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    UIView *customBackgroundView;

}

// m-file

customBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

The result: it doesn't work. customBackgroundView is still nil. My conclusion is that either I'm crazy or X Code is broken.

Comment: haha...clean your project and restart it then...XCode does act up at times

Comment: @tipycalFlow cleaned and restarted several times already... :)

Comment: NSLog directly [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)] to see if it's nil (which should not). If it's not nil, try to change customBackgroundView into a NSString and use customBackgroundView=@"My string";